# How estimate mean of column and row in a list of data frames?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, syntax-error, mean

I'm trying to estimate the mean of every subgroup of data, this is hold the   number of rows and columns adn estimate the mean. therefore, I should get a data   frame 5x7x1, but I'm confusing and I can't deal with this. Any help will be so   appreciated.

I get the following data :

```
list = data  
data$1= data frame (5 x 7 x 10 )  
data$2 = data frame (5 x 7 x 10 )  
data$3 = data frame (5 x 7 x 10 )
```

my last try was:

```
data <- list()
for (i in seq_along(myVariablesImp)){
data[[i]] <- abind(myVariablesImp[[i]], along = 5)
data[[i]] <-  apply(data[[i]], c(2:9), mean)
}
```

this not working because estimate the mean of  the rows (if I replace along =   for 10 or 7, show an dimension error)

Comment: What do you mean by `(5 x 7 x 10 )` Do you mean the dimension of the data frame is 10 matrices with 5 rows and 7 columns ? Is this an array with `dim(array) 5,7,10`? Elaborate

Comment: Hi Onyambu! Yes, 10 matrices and I need the mean of every column and row of my three dataframe. Cheers!

Comment: for the matrices, use `colMeans` and `rowMeans`. I still don't understand how you have matrices in a dataframe. can you have a `dput` of your data here? Or a sample?